# Conda activate environment looks in wrong directory

Tags: python-3.x, environment, conda

After performing a fresh install of Miniconda, restarting, doing `conda update conda` in cmd, and copying an old environment folder into the `envs directories` as listed by `conda info`, activating this environment does not work: it looks for the environment in the wrong directory `C:/Program`, a directory that doesn't exist on my PC.

[Conda commands in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5wGU.png)

Is this a bug in the new version of conda? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the path to default, uninstalling, rebooting, and reinstalling miniconda did the trick. I think this is a bug in the file activate.bat